# Short url not working with fetch API in Netlify but working on local server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I developed an app with react social media app. I've handled all the ajax request with built in fetch API. Every request parameter war short URL, eg.

```
fetch('/posts/dp/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
})
```

and in my `package.json` file I've set my proxy to `"proxy": "https://social-firegram.herokuapp.com/api"`. The request works fine in localhost with this setup. But when I deployed my app in Netlify the app is not sending any request to my backend app.

### Now my question is:

Should I turn all my short request url `'/posts/dp/upload'` into full request url `'https://social-firegram.herokuapp.com/api/posts/dp/upload'`. Although I've tried this localhost (with the proxy still there) and this kind of request is hitting the server but not sending the cookie in it's header which contains a `jwt` token and for that my backend cannot authenticate my request and I'm not getting an `401 (unauthenticated)` error code. Now what should I do to make my frontend send request to my backend with a cookie.

**NB:** I purposely didn't use `axios`.

Comment: What does your [Netlify proxy configuration](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/#proxy-to-another-service) look like?

Comment: Regarding cookies, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included

Comment: This helped a lot @Phil